# Run application as guest or with limited privileges under Windows without having to relogin?

Tags: windows, admin, privileges

How can I start an application to run as guest or to run with limited privileges under Windows 7?

The current user is an admin and I want to test the behaviour of the application while running with less rights.

I already know that it has some issues on other systems but I want to run it on my computer/account to debug it.

Comment: In Windows 7, all applications should run with limited privileges by default.  If you've disabled UAC, try turning it back on.

Comment: Note that depending on the nature of the problem you're trying to debug, it may be necessary to actually create a limited user account and log on with it in order to reproduce the problem.  By all means try other steps first, but keep in mind that they aren't fully reproducing the end user's environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold shift key and right-click executable and select "Run as different user".
Apologies if your question was seeking a programmatic solution.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware about the `Shift-Click` option, it will be helpful in the future. Still, this doesn't solve my issue because I want to run it as Guest or Limited user and I do not have such an account (domain).